# Avoid full page figure in a multicol document being pushed to the end of the document

Tags: multicol, includegraphics, fullpage

I'm trying to insert a fullpage figure in a 2 columns document using multicol. I know this is a long lasting problems but all "solutions" found online do not do the job. My MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
bottom=22mm,
top=22mm,
left=15mm,
right=15mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section*{section 1}
            \lipsum[1-8]
        \section*{section 2}
            \lipsum[1-2]
            \begin{figure*}[!ht]
                \hrule
                \vspace{2mm}
                \centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{FullPageFigure.pdf}
                \vspace{1mm}
                \hrule
            \end{figure*}
            \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This results in the fullpage figure being pushed to the end of the document for no apparent reason:

[image]

However if I slightly change the size of the figure with:

```
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{FullPageFigure.pdf}
```

The figure is correctly placed after the first page of the document with the remaining text:

[image]

I've tried with `\usepackage{placeins}` and `\FloatBarrier` but they are not adapted for multicol environments.

Also the only "working" solution that can be found online (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856189/fullpage-picture-in-two-column-layout)) is to end the multicol environment  before placing the figure and then starting it again. Which is clearly not a viaable solution.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Did you try loading the `stfloats` package and the `[t]` option (or`[b]` if you prefer) with `figure*`. Other than that, you have the `strip` environment from `midfloat` (same bundle: `sttools`).

Comment: you removed the p from the float options, so it can't go on a float page. Try with `\begin{figure*}[!htp]` instead.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ulrike Fischer, you may want to post this as an anwer so I can point it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed the `p` from the float options, so it can't go on a float page.

Use `\begin{figure*}[!htp]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ulrike spotted one issue, which prevents from being placed: if on t being allowed it (h doesn't work on wide floats) then it will never get placed because it is too large for the top area, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39019/10109 for a discussion.

But the other is its placement in the source. If you explicitly mark the position where you put your float with, say `{\Large Here}` you will see that this point is on the second page. Thus it can only go after that page (being full height) which brings it up to page 3 (as a minimum).

With the smaller graphic, float and callout both fit onto page 2 which is why you see it there.